# Can you run a flatpak from a single file?

Tags: flatpak

Things like `snap` or `flatpak` irritate me to no end, because they take over your system (and `snap` even updates packages behind the scenes without informing you, so you end up with a shitton of crap dependencies eventually, so you then have to manually delete old snap packages - one would even with someone would invent something like a "computer", that could run something like a "program", to do that automatically and spare you the trouble of manually removing dependencies).

Anyways, I like to keep my primary OS (for now Ubuntu 20.04) very thin, so it fits in some 20-30 GB, and then I like to run other apps that I do not use often from external drives. Sometimes I can unpack a `.deb` and use it like that; sometimes there is an AppImage which also works for me.

So, now I have that problem, that I want to try `pitivi` - and unfortunately, they moved to using `flatpak` - and if you want to build from source, you still *must* use flatpak https://developer.pitivi.org/HACKING.html?gi-language=undefined ... I've tried to setup that development environment on a different machine, and there's like hundreds of megs of dependencies ...

Anyways, if I'm able to complete a build from source for pitivi in this development environment - could I somehow export a single file (say a `.flatpak` file or something), which I could have on an external hard drive, and I could run it with the system's `flatpak` command, say like:

```
flatpak /media/external_drive/pitivi_build.flatpak ## pseudocode
```

If it is possible to export such a single "runnable" flatpak file, how would I do that?

Comment: If you don't like flatpaks, I suggest you switch to Mint or Debian (debian has a `pitivi` .deb package, version 2022.06-1+b1. I assume Mint does too).  They don't force them on you.  Aside from that, you'll find them pretty much the same as Ubuntu, with .deb files and dpkg and apt.   Personally, I have no interest in using flatpak or snap - IMO they just bring the shittiness of android & iphone app stores to linux - but don't really care all that much as long as they're optional...I was horrified to hear some time ago that Ubuntu is effectively making them mandatory.

Comment: sadly, it looks like pitivi on Mint might be a flatpak too now.  A comment by someone on https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/pitivi says that they're switching to kdenlive because pitivi's a flatpak.

Comment: to answer your question: I don't think so, no. But you could tell flatpak that the storage location of flatpak'ed applications is in any location (as long as the filesystem supports unix permissions, and SELinux contexts, IIRC). Also, you could try to convert a RPM specification into a deb package and do the build yourself based on that. But yes, no matter how you toss and turn: pitivi is a GUI tool with extensive dependencies in video editing, video hardware interfacing, codecs, GUI toolsets…; building it will take a couple GB of space, if I had to take a wild guess, and require GBs of deps.